# How do I list all installed packages with specific version numbers?

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I would like to list all the installed packages, with specific version numbers on my system.  I checked out `dpkg --get-selections` ([How to list all installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages)) but it doesn't show me what I need.  For example:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections apache2
apache2                                         install
```

shows that apache2 is installed, however not the version.  I recently did a `apt-get upgrade` so apache2.2.22-1 *should* be version installed (http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/apache2.2-common), but how can I show that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 36):

Use `dpkg -l` instead.

### Example:

```
dpkg -l | grep '^ii' | grep skype
```

Outputs this:

```
alaa@aa-lu:~$ dpkg -l | grep '^ii' | grep skype
ii    skype      4.2.0.11-0ubuntu0.12.04.2       i386     client for Skype VOIP...
```

If you only want to extract the name and version, you can do this:

```
dpkg -l | grep '^ii' | grep skype | awk '{print $2 "\t" $3}'
```

Which will only print the second and third column from the above output, like this:

```
alaa@aa-lu:~$ dpkg -l | grep '^ii' | grep skype | awk '{print $2 "\t" $3}'
skype   4.2.0.11-0ubuntu0.12.04.2
```

Of course, if you want to list **all** of your installed packages with their versions, and not only Skype, then just remove the `grep skype` part to make the command like this:

```
dpkg -l | grep '^ii' | awk '{print $2 "\t" $3}'
```

Comment: I was noticing dpkg -l truncating version numbers if they were longer than 21 characters, and like all package versions are like 22 characters long. :(

Answer (score 15):

Use

```
dpkg-query --show apache2
```

to get the version number for package `apache2` and

```
dpkg-query --show
```

to get the version numbers for all installed packages

Comment: Your solution gave me ~20% more packages than `dpkg -l | grep '^ii' | awk '{print $2 "\t" $3}'`. Do you know what the difference is?

Comment: @Thomas Jensen:  Thanks for spotting this. `dpkg-query --show` actually doesn't show the *installed* packages, but the *not not-installed* ones. That is it shows e.g. half-installed packages or packages with remaining config files, too.